# Differential equation has solution of form $AV^{β_1 }?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

in this equation 
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\sigma^2 V^2 F^{''} (V)+(\rho-\delta)VF^{'}(V)-\rho F=0,$$

$\sigma, \rho$ and  $\delta$ are constants, and V y F are functions en dollars, why the solution take the form $AV^{\beta -1}$?

Comment: I just realised that due to my awful smartphone that I wrote in the edit $\beta_1$ instead of $\beta -1$ which ultimately does not matter but just making it clear :).

Answer (score 0):

The equation in question is $\frac{\alpha^2}{2}V^2F''(V)+(\rho - \delta)VF'(V)-\rho F=0$.

It is Euler's equation. Substitute $V = e^t$ and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

This is the equation $$aV^2F''(V)+bVF'(V)+cF(V)=0,$$ for some suitable $(a,b,c)$. By linearity, the function $F:V\mapsto F(V)=\alpha V^\beta$ solves this equation, for some $\alpha\ne0$, if and only if the function $F:V\mapsto F(V)=V^\beta$ solves it. If $F:V\mapsto F(V)=V^\beta$ then $$F'(V)=\beta V^{\beta-1},\qquad F''(V)=\beta(\beta-1) V^{\beta-2},$$ hence this happens if and only if
$$
a\beta(\beta-1)+b\beta+c=0.
$$
Now, solve this quadratic equation in $\beta$. When the two roots $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are distinct (for example, as here, because $ac\lt0$), the linear combinations $$F:V\mapsto F(V)=\alpha_1 V^{\beta_1}+\alpha_2 V^{\beta_2},$$ span the space of solutions.